# onOpen function does not respond as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

my onOpen function does not respond as expected. The UI is loaded but it does not jump to the last free row. Strangely enough when I change the sign in the script it jumps to the second to last line.

Do any of you have any idea what the reason is?

Below is the script.

```
//Create an UI menu and skip to first free row in range B:B
function onOpen() {
  
  skipToLastRow();
  getUi();
  
}
function skipToLastRow() {
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ss = sheet.getSheetByName('KPI Tracker');
  const lr = ss.getLastRow();

    ss.getRange(lr +1,2).activate();

}


function getUi() {    
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Script Launcher');

    ui.addItem('⏰ ETA request','requestEta')
    ui.addItem(' Update ETAs','etaCheck')
    ui.addSeparator()
    ui.addItem(' Send Short report','sendRep')
    ui.addToUi();

}
```

Comment: Works fine with me... Sure the sheetname is correct?

Comment: Hi I found out why it does not works fine for me. I have also 2 columns with checkboxes applied to the last row. Now I try to figure out how I can ignore the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a formula in you're sheet that uses bad practices and therefore script will pick this up as last row:

```
//Bad:
=IF(A1 <> "RemcoE33","","Hi dude!")

//Good:
=IF(A1 <> "RemcoE33",,"Hi dude!")
```

You want to leave out the "". This will be picked up as values in apps script.

Comment: Hi @RemcoE33, that's not the issue. Apps Script ignore the formulas. It is because of the checkboxes. I have tested it. Formulas, for e.g. in A1:A500, are stored. Checkboxes, for e.g. C1:C300, are stored. Visible Values, for e.g. B1:B100, are stored. The script ignores the formulas and jumps automatically to row 300, because of the Checkboxes. And it doesn't matter if the checkboxes are declared with value or not. Any ideas how I can tell the script how to ignore the column C which contains the checkboxes? my formulas were =ISOCalendarweek and =weekday and also a calculation like =F1/G1.

Comment: @AgisDominikHinzmann maybe it's time for a [sample](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) sheet?

Comment: Hi RemcooE33, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/182Od8UT54RDvjfKDJIkdcMnz2CODE3mg8G1d0PmpszA/edit?usp=sharing that is my test sheet. please feel free to check it out.